# SQL join issue - joining two related queries (Full Outer Join)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been battling with this for days. I'm no expert with SQL and have managed to create a few queries, however I'm having a real job joing the queries up.

For example, I want to join the following two queries:

```
SELECT publication_id AS Pure_Publication_Id, caa.person_id, 
    caa.name_first_name AS Primary_Author_First_Name, 
    caa.name_last_name AS Primary_Author_Last_Name
FROM pure.classified_author_assoc caa
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Pure.Publication
        ON Caa.Publication_Id = Publication.Id
WHERE Caa.Person_Id  IS NOT NULL
    AND publication.id IN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT pure.publication_project_assoc.publication_id
        FROM Pure.project
            JOIN Pure.Publication_project_assoc
                ON project.id = Pure.Publication_project_assoc.project_id
        WHERE pure.project.source_id IN ('XEP378', 'XES049', 'YAH001')
    )
GROUP BY publication_id, caa.person_id, caa.name_first_name, caa.name_last_name;
```

and

```
SELECT publication.id AS Pure_Publication_Id
    COUNT (person_id) AS "NUMBER_OF_AUTHORS", 
    CASE WHEN COUNT (person_id) > 1 THEN 'Yes' 
        else 'No' END AS Additional_Authors
FROM pure.classified_author_assoc caa
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Pure.Publication
        ON Caa.Publication_Id = Publication.Id
WHERE Caa.Person_Id  IS NOT NULL
    AND publication.id IN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT pure.publication_project_assoc.publication_id
        FROM Pure.project
            JOIN Pure.Publication_project_assoc
                ON project.id = Pure.Publication_project_assoc.project_id
        WHERE pure.project.source_id IN ('XEP378', 'XES049', 'YAH001')
    )
GROUP BY publication.id;
```

I cannot combine them in a single query (I don't think) as the first query would only return Number_of_authors as one. However, when I try to run the query will a full join in the middle as below, I get a SQL command not ended properly error at the end of the first sql statement and I'm not sure what the join should be on at the end.

```
SELECT publication_id AS Pure_Publication_Id, caa.person_id, 
    caa.name_first_name AS Primary_Author_First_Name,
    caa.name_last_name AS Primary_Author_Last_Name
FROM pure.classified_author_assoc caa
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Pure.Publication
        ON Caa.Publication_Id = Publication.Id
WHERE Caa.Person_Id  IS NOT NULL
    AND publication.id IN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT pure.publication_project_assoc.publication_id
        FROM Pure.project
            JOIN Pure.Publication_project_assoc
                ON project.id = Pure.Publication_project_assoc.project_id
        WHERE pure.project.source_id IN ('XEP378', 'XES049', 'YAH001')
    )
GROUP BY publication_id, caa.person_id, caa.name_first_name, caa.name_last_name
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT publication.id AS Pure_Publication_Id, 
        COUNT (person_id) AS "NUMBER_OF_AUTHORS", 
        CASE WHEN COUNT (person_id) > 1 THEN 'Yes' 
            else 'No' END AS Additional_Authors
    FROM pure.classified_author_assoc caa
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Pure.Publication
            ON Caa.Publication_Id = Publication.Id
    WHERE Caa.Person_Id  IS NOT NULL
        AND publication.id IN
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT pure.publication_project_assoc.publication_id
            FROM Pure.project
                JOIN Pure.Publication_project_assoc
                    ON project.id = Pure.Publication_project_assoc.project_id
            WHERE pure.project.source_id IN ('XEP378', 'XES049', 'YAH001')
        )
)
GROUP BY publication.id
ON ****;
```

I have tried this every way I can think of and know it should be something simple. Can anybody help please?

Comment: Is it possible to explain this problem with non complex sample?

Answer (score 1):

You have to JOIN the second query to the FROM clause of the first. It also appears to me that you might really be after a LEFT JOIN not a FULL JOIN. Perhaps a WITH clause might help a bit:

```
WITH q AS (
(SELECT publication.id AS Pure_Publication_Id, COUNT (person_id) AS "NUMBER_OF_AUTHORS", CASE WHEN COUNT (person_id) > 1 THEN 'Yes' else 'No' END AS Additional_Authors
...
)
SELECT publication_id AS Pure_Publication_Id, caa.person_id, caa.name_first_name AS Primary_Author_First_Name, caa.name_last_name AS Primary_Author_Last_Name, q.NUMBER_OF_AUTHORS, q.additional_authors 
  FROM pure.classified_author_assoc caa 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN Pure.Publication ON Caa.Publication_Id = Publication.Id
          LEFT OUTER JOIN q ON publication_id = q.pure_publication_id
 WHERE Caa.Person_Id  IS NOT NULL 
   AND publication.id IN 
       (SELECT DISTINCT pure.publication_project_assoc.publication_id
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT FirstQuery.*, SecondQuery.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT publication_id AS Pure_Publication_Id, caa.person_id, 
            caa.name_first_name AS Primary_Author_First_Name,
            caa.name_last_name AS Primary_Author_Last_Name
        FROM pure.classified_author_assoc caa
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Pure.Publication
                ON Caa.Publication_Id = Publication.Id
        WHERE Caa.Person_Id  IS NOT NULL
            AND EXISTS
            (
                SELECT 1 
                FROM Pure.project
                JOIN Pure.Publication_project_assoc
                    ON project.id = Pure.Publication_project_assoc.project_id
                WHERE pure.publication_project_assoc.publication_id = publication.id
                    AND pure.project.source_id IN ('XEP378', 'XES049', 'YAH001')
        )
        GROUP BY publication_id, caa.person_id, caa.name_first_name, caa.name_last_name
    ) AS FirstQuery
    FULL OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT publication.id AS Pure_Publication_Id, 
            COUNT (person_id) AS "NUMBER_OF_AUTHORS", 
            CASE WHEN COUNT (person_id) > 1 THEN 'Yes' 
                else 'No' END AS Additional_Authors
        FROM pure.classified_author_assoc caa
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Pure.Publication
                ON Caa.Publication_Id = Publication.Id
        WHERE Caa.Person_Id  IS NOT NULL
            AND EXISTS
            (
                SELECT 1 
                FROM Pure.project
                    JOIN Pure.Publication_project_assoc
                        ON project.id = Pure.Publication_project_assoc.project_id
                WHERE pure.publication_project_assoc.publication_id = publication.id
                    AND pure.project.source_id IN ('XEP378', 'XES049', 'YAH001')
            )
       GROUP BY publication.id
    ) AS SecondQuery
        ON FirstQuery.Pure_Publication_Id = SecondQuery.Pure_Publication_Id
```

There is probably a way to do this a lot neater, but this is how you should perform your `FULL OUTER JOIN`.  It is using nested queries. Now, keep in mind that  `FULL OUTER JOIN` will return NULL results if `FirstQuery` does not have any count. So, I suggest changing it to a `LEFT JOIN`. This will make sure there is a value in `FirstQuery`, but it wont care if there is no matching value in the `SecondQuery`

**UPDATE FOR OPTIMIZATION POINTS/NOTES**

- By adding `publication.id IN`, you cancel out your `LEFT JOIN`. If you want it to truly be a `LEFT JOIN`, then this filter criteria must be put into the `LEFT JOIN`'s `ON` statement
- Changed your `IN` to be an `EXISTS` to cut down on clutter and achieve the same result

Comment: Thanks Justin, the issue is that the columns are not identical, is there a way round this? Not sure how to simplify the query either, I have been tearing my hair out. I've tried Union All and I'm still getting the same error message. Any ideas please?

Comment: @Scott I updated my answer as I didnt see the columns were different. This is still ugly, but will work

Comment: Thanks Justin, you have saved my life. I need to work on my SQL a lot more as I know this is very ugly, but it's achieved the result. For some reason, it still wouldn't work with the ")as FirstQuery/SecondQuery" and I had to remove the AS for it to work. Thanks again for all your help, you're a star!